# Getting ViewContext in asp net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, html-helper

I had an HTML extension in .NET 4.6 like this one

```
public static string IsSelected( this HtmlHelper html, string controller = null, string action = null, string area = null ) {
    string cssClass = "active";
    string currentAction = (string)html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values[ "action" ];
    string currentController = (string)html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values[ "controller" ];
    string currentArea = html.ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens[ "area" ] == null ? String.Empty : (string)html.ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens[ "area" ];

    if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty( controller ) )
        controller = currentController;

    if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty( action ) )
        action = currentAction;

    if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty( area ) )
        area = currentArea;

    if ( controller.ToLower() == currentController.ToLower() && action.ToLower() == currentAction.ToLower() && area == currentArea ) {
        return cssClass;
    }
    else {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Through this helper I was able to write code like this in a razor view:

```
<li class="treeview @Html.IsSelected( controller: "mycontroller", action : string.Empty, area : string.Empty )">
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> <span>Menu 1</span>
        <span class="pull-right-container">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
        </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
        <li class="@Html.IsSelected( controller: "mycontroller", action : "myaction", area : string.Empty )">
            <a href="@Url.Action("myaction", "mycontroller" )">
                <i class="fa fa-retweet"></i>
                My Action &nbsp;
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

How can I convert this helper to be used with .NET Core? I have tried by using `IHtmlContent` but I cannot get the `ViewContext`. The only way is a tag helper?

Comment: did you find a way to get the viewcontext?

Comment: unfortunately not. I have setup my code into a TagHelper.

Comment: check this out then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039269/create-custom-html-helper-in-asp-net-core/51466436#51466436

Answer (score 2):

Maybe quite late, but you can get it via:

`this.ViewContext`

when you are within a cshtml file