# .NET CORE MvcHtmlString(TextboxFor, LabelFor).ToString() Error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

Hello i must convert MvcHtmlString to string. I was using before this code.(.net framework)

```
TagBuilder div = new TagBuilder("div");
div.MergeAttribute("class", "form-group");
var label = helper.LabelFor(expression, new { @class = "control-label col-lg-1" });
div.InnerHtml += label.ToString();
```

Now I am developing .net core and I get error at

```
div.InnerHtml += label.ToString();
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOhfo.png)

> Returns a string that represent the current object.
>   Reference to type 'HtmlString' claims it is defined in 'System.Web', but it could not be found.
>   Module 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a should be referenced

Please help me. I must use this method or alternative. I am trying build a form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line below causing error because `TagBuilder.InnerHtml` is a read only property and you can't use `+=` operator to assign HTML string:

```
div.InnerHtml += label.ToString();
```

What you should do is using `AppendHtml()` against existing `LabelFor` helper:

```
div.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(label);
```

Take note that .NET Core MVC doesn't use `System.Web` namespace, it uses `Microsoft.AspNetCore` parent namespace instead. You should try `IHtmlContent` to build your own custom helper instead of `MvcHtmlString`, by following these steps:

1) Include all `using` statements provided below to enable `IHtmlContent` and `IHtmlHelper` instance.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
```

2) Create your custom helper using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper` as parameter instead of `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper`, shown in example below:

```
public static IHtmlContent CustomLabelFor<TModel, TProperty>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
    string result;

    TagBuilder div = new TagBuilder("div");
    div.MergeAttribute("class", "form-group");
    var label = helper.LabelFor(expression, new { @class = "control-label col-lg-1" });
    div.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(label);

    using (var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
    {
        div.WriteTo(sw, System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder.Default);
        result = sw.ToString();
    }

    return new HtmlString(result);
}
```

**Note:** This example helper already tested in VS 2017, .NET Core 2.1.

Related issue:

[Create Custom HTML Helper in ASP.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039269/create-custom-html-helper-in-asp-net-core/43511322)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?:

```
div.InnerHtml += label.ToHtmlString();
```

Comment: There is no such a method ToHtmlString() in my visualstudio >.<

Comment: @HaroMaro You should implement `System.Web.HtmlString`

Comment: Also I found this on [another forum](https://forums.asp.net/t/1755956.aspx?Help+Cannot+implicitly+convert+type+string+to+System+Web+HtmlString+)
`HtmlString str = new HtmlString(label.value);`
Try it as well and let me know if this did the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your interest but dont work these. label has only .GetType, .Equals .GetHashCode methods :(