# How to access HtmlHelper from custom RazorPage type in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

In ASP.NET MVC 4/5, I used to create my custom WebViewPage to add some methods that I can access from my razor view with a shorter, concise syntax as the following example

```
public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    public string T(string translationKey)
    {
        return Html.Translate(translationKey);
    }
}
```

In the Razor page, I can use `@T` instead of `@Html.Translate`

```
@T("/path1/path2")
```

However, in ASP.NET Core 6, I tried to create my custom razor page type (**see 2nd screenshot**) and found RazorPage type doesn't expose `HtmlHelper` property, therefore I'm unable to access the inner HtmlHelper like how I did in in traditional ASP.NET MVC 4/5 (**see 1st screenshot**).

[image]

[image]

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.webviewpage-1?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2), `WebViewPage<TModel>` Class is not applicable to Asp.Net Core 6.

You can use `IHtmlHelper` to continue to customize HtmlHelper like this:

```
public static IHtmlContent T(this IHtmlHelper html)
            => new HtmlString("<div> Hello World </div>");
```

And in Razor Page:

```
<h1>@Html.T()</h1>
```

For more details please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039269/create-custom-html-helper-in-asp-net-core).

Comment: I understand I can build custom html helper or taghelper. However it doesn't give me the shorter syntax as what I need. I'm building my custom RazorPage type and would like to mimic what I have in ASP.NET MVC 4/5

Comment: For custom RazorPage type, you can take a look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-US/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0#directives), but `WebViewPage<TModel>` doesn't seem to be accepted by `@inherits`.

Comment: That's how I implemented the custom razor page. My question is how can I access the HtmlHelper instance from custom razor page. I update my original post with more details

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to your project;

```xml
<EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
```

You'll see that your generated pages contain something like;

```cs
[global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]
public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<TModel> Html { get; private set; } = default!;
```

I think that this property will be injected from `HttpContext.RequestServices` by [RazorPagePropertyActivator](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Mvc/Mvc.Razor/src/RazorPagePropertyActivator.cs#L119).

If you are using `@inherits` to change the base view class, I don't think you can inject services via a constructor. But you can probably define your own properties with the above `[RazorInject]` attribute, like the non-generic `IHtmlHelper`. Or you could resolve the correct service on demand inside a method.

For translation specifically, the asp.net core documentation suggest using the [IViewLocalizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0#view-localization) service via an explicit injected dependency, which you could add to [`_ViewImports`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-6.0#importing-shared-directives) with a single character variable name. Avoiding the need to create your own base view class.