# How to build modular ASP.NET Razor Components in a MVC Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages, blazor-server-side

I like to create a ASP.NET MVC Application, where the pages are rendered on the server side. After reading a lot of documentation I couldn't find a way to achieve a modular way of creating components.

I found a [way to create Custom Tag Helpers](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/custom-tag-helpers) and a [way to create Razor Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0). But somehow I can't use a Razor Component in a Razor Component.

So what I basically want to do is to write some Razor components, which I can reuse in other Razor Components and so build my app modular.

For better understanding a simple example:

I want to write a component like a Button. Then I want to create a second component, called Icon.

For example: index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<Button text="Click me" link="/" iconclass="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></Button>
```

The Button component should look something like:
Button.razor

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="@link">Click me <Icon iconclass="@iconclass"></Icon></a>
```

And the icon component like:
Icon.razor

```
<i class="@iconclass"></i>
```

This should render the following HTML Code:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/">Click me <i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></a>
```

I achieved it, to include one component in index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<component type="typeof(Button)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>
```

but when I do the same in the razor Component, it does not work.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary">
    Click me
    <component type="typeof(Icon)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</a>
```

Is there a way to achieve such a modular structure in ASP.Net?

Comment: Are you talking about Html helper?

Comment: If there is a way to create a custom HTML Helper, which I can reuse in different Razor components, that would be a feasible solution.

Comment: Of course u can create ur own html helper

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  I really appreciate your help. How do I use a html helper in a rezor component?

Comment: are you using MVC5 or Core?

Comment: I'm using Core.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039269/create-custom-html-helper-in-asp-net-core

Comment: You need to do some configuration to be able to use razor components in asp.net core razor pages project. Have you done that? This tutorial could help: https://medium.com/capgemini-microsoft-team/using-blazor-in-your-existing-asp-net-core-mvc-applications-f1b09bd66f4b

Comment: Refer to the answer give by Sakib from the link I share you. Works similar to custom HTML helper. No Configuration needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the links. I already did the tutorial from medium and everything worked fine. More interesting is the link from stackoverflow you posted. However, I get the following error when I insert this in my code. I don't know why:

Argument of type HtmlHelper is missing. 

What do I have to pass as a first parameter?

Comment: Are HTML Helper functions available in Core? I can not use @Html. What do I miss?